# XmlSerializer.Deserialize() keeps return null and throws no error

Tags: c#, xml, web-services

I'm trying to deserialize responce from web service.

Responce:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <currency>
      <id><![CDATA[1]]></id>
      <name><![CDATA[Złoty]]></name>
      <iso_code><![CDATA[PLN]]></iso_code>
      <iso_code_num><![CDATA[985]]></iso_code_num>
      <blank><![CDATA[1]]></blank>
      <sign><![CDATA[zł]]></sign>
      <format><![CDATA[2]]></format>
      <decimals><![CDATA[1]]></decimals>
      <conversion_rate><![CDATA[1.000000]]></conversion_rate>
      <deleted><![CDATA[0]]></deleted>
      <active><![CDATA[1]]></active>
    </currency>
  </prestashop>
```

My class code:

```
public class prestashop
{
   Currency currency;
}

public class Currency
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public string iso_code;
    public int iso_code_num;
    public int blank;
    public string sign;
    public int format;
    public int decimals;
    public float conversion_rate;
    public bool deleted;
    public bool active;
}
```

And finally part where I try to deserialize:

```
Prestashop_WebClient client = new Prestashop_WebClient();
prestashop objpresta = new prestashop();
StreamReader strumien = client.ReadRecord("currencies", "1");
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(prestashop));
objpresta = (prestashop)ser.Deserialize(strumien);
strumien.Close();
```

When I run the code, object objpresta is null after deserializing but there is no error.

I would be very thankful for any help.

Comment: not an answer but you should use the `using` statement instead of closing the stream manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.....

Usings.....

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
```

Classes.....

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "currency")]
public class Currency
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "id")]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "iso_code")]
    public string Iso_code { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "iso_code_num")]
    public string Iso_code_num { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "blank")]
    public string Blank { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "sign")]
    public string Sign { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "format")]
    public string Format { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "decimals")]
    public string Decimals { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "conversion_rate")]
    public string Conversion_rate { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "deleted")]
    public string Deleted { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "active")]
    public string Active { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "prestashop")]
public class Prestashop
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "currency")]
    public Currency Currency { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xlink", Namespace = "http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/")]
    public string Xlink { get; set; }
}
```

Code.....

```
        string strXML = File.ReadAllText("xml.xml");
        byte[] bufXML = ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strXML);
        MemoryStream ms1 = new MemoryStream(bufXML);

        // Deserialize to object
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Prestashop));
        try
        {
            using (XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(ms1))
            {
                Prestashop deserializedXML = (Prestashop)serializer.Deserialize(reader);

            }// put a break point here and mouse-over Label1Text and Label2Text ….
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw;
        }
```

Your XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <currency>
      <id><![CDATA[1]]></id>
      <name><![CDATA[Złoty]]></name>
      <iso_code><![CDATA[PLN]]></iso_code>
      <iso_code_num><![CDATA[985]]></iso_code_num>
      <blank><![CDATA[1]]></blank>
      <sign><![CDATA[zł]]></sign>
      <format><![CDATA[2]]></format>
      <decimals><![CDATA[1]]></decimals>
      <conversion_rate><![CDATA[1.000000]]></conversion_rate>
      <deleted><![CDATA[0]]></deleted>
      <active><![CDATA[1]]></active>
    </currency>
  </prestashop>
```

I am reading your XML in to a string from a file in the application build folder called xml.xml... you will need to get the XML string from somewhere else or create the xml.xml file and save your XML for the code above to work

Answer (score 0):

You're spelling all properties exactly like the XML elements, so there's not need to add `[XmlElement]` for each property. But I think the `XmlRootAttribute` is missing:

```
[XmlRoot("currency")]
public class Currency
...
```